# How do I testfor anyone that is not the specified player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would think that it would look like

```
/testfor [name=PLAYER1,name=PLAYER2,name=PLAYER3,r=50]
```

I am trying to kill anyone that is not player 1, 2 or 3, and was planning on using a `testfor` command, but if it is better without, by all means go ahead.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your current idea that I want to address before providing you a working setup.

#### Problem 1

`/testfor` won't do you any good. All that command will ever do is test if there exists an entity in the game currently that matches the target selector and (if defined) data tag. Having a `/testfor` command check for anyone but those three players and then using a comparator an a `/kill` command does not transfer the targets to the kill command.

Luckily for you, there's no need for that, since `/kill` itself has a `<target>` argument, meaning that you can ditch the `/testfor` entirely.

#### Problem 2

Multiply defined target selector arguments only keep the *last* specified value. If you have something like `@a[name=Alice,name=Bob]`, only Bob will be targeted, not Alice, because the game already forgot that her name was specified.

#### Solution

You need to assign a single unique something to the three names. This something can be a scoreboard value, a team, or (in 1.9) a scoreboard tag. Either of those is fine, and which one works best depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. I'll use a team as an example here. The [scoreboard commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Command_reference) wiki page lists all the commands needed.

Set up a team (I call it `noKill`) and add the three players.

```
/scoreboard teams add noKill 
/scoreboard teams join noKill PLAYER1 PLAYER2 PLAYER3
```

Now, open your command block and type

```
/kill @a[team=!noKill,r=50]
```

Note the `!` in front of the team name, which negates the team argument. The selector will now kill everyone in a 50 foot spherical radius around the command block that is *not* in the `noKill` team when powered.

Comment: As pertaining to the inverse !, wouldn't this work for names? Ex. @a[name=!Lemon]?

Comment: @Judge2020 Yes. But you still couldn't specify more than 1 name that way, i.e. `@a[name=!Alice,name=!Bob]` would still target Alice, because the game only looks for people not called Bob.